# Grant access to SPA from Spring Boot oauth2login

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm looking to integrate with Twitter's twitterv2 API. The goal is to enable the backend to fetch the OAuth2 access token from Twitter and execute requests on behalf of a user which uses the SPA.

From my understanding, the backend needs to be the OAuth client since it's the component who needs to access the (Twitter API) resources server endpoints.

So far, my app is designed for the backend to redirect the SPA to the Twitter login and then back to the SPA. In local, it works since I can share the `JSESSIONID` cookie between localhost instances but when I deploy my app and I don't have the same domain for both backend and frontend, there is no way for the SPA to login.

I feel like my backend needs to be an resource server as well as a resource client for my use case to work since the SPA needs to login with Twitter to access it's resouces. Am I missing something?

Here's my Spring Security config class:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Value("${front_end.baseUrl}")
    private String front_end_baseUrl;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user/isUserLoggedIn","/generate/customModel","/generate/customModel/test","/pay","/pay/****").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .cors(withDefaults())
            .csrf().disable()
            .oauth2Login()
                .tokenEndpoint()
                    .accessTokenResponseClient(accessTokenResponseClient())
                        .and()
                .and()
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequest> accessTokenResponseClient(){
        DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient accessTokenResponseClient =
                new DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient();
        accessTokenResponseClient.setRequestEntityConverter(new CustomRequestEntityConverter());

        OAuth2AccessTokenResponseHttpMessageConverter tokenResponseHttpMessageConverter =
                new OAuth2AccessTokenResponseHttpMessageConverter();

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(Arrays.asList(
                new FormHttpMessageConverter(), tokenResponseHttpMessageConverter));
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new OAuth2ErrorResponseErrorHandler());

        accessTokenResponseClient.setRestOperations(restTemplate);
        return accessTokenResponseClient;
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList(front_end_baseUrl));

        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"));

        configuration.addAllowedHeader("content-type");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("Authorization");
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);

        return source;
    }

}
```

Comment: What does *it works since I can share the JSESSIONID cookie between localhost instances* mean? Your backend could set a session cookie and your SPA could use it to access your backend. That is no problem with different domains.